# Pegar informações de um foreach com outro foreach

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, foreach

Tenho uma busca mysql que me traz o seguinte array ao utilizar um foreach, tenho uma outra busca sql que me traz todos os field de uma tabela que nos caso são os mesmos nomes de field que estão abaixo usr_tbl_ssid... como faço para exibir apenas o valor de contacts_form_name, whatsapp e no lado os nomes dos campos e ao mesmo tempo ocultar os campos vazios?

```
Array
(
    [usr_tbl_ssid] => 
    [0] => 
    [contacts_form_name] => Fye Flourigh
    [1] => Fye Flourigh
    [whatsapp] => +5521999
    [2] => +5521888
    [email] => 
    [3] => 
    [site] => 
    [4] => 
    [facebook] => 
    [5] => 
    [messenger] => 
    [6] => 
)
```

Meu código até agora está assim

```
$statement = $conect -> prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $usr_");
$statement -> execute();
$user_table_columns = $statement -> fetchAll();
foreach($user_table_columns as $user_columns => $columns) {
    $array_columns[] = $columns["Field"]; }

$statement = $conect -> prepare("SELECT * FROM $usr_ WHERE contacts_form_name = :contacts_form_name LIMIT 1");
$statement -> bindValue(":contacts_form_name", $_POST['search_content']);
$statement -> execute();
$_SESSION["search_send"] = $statement -> fetchAll();
foreach($_SESSION["search_send"] as $contacts_form => $search_data_content) {
    $array_data[] = $search_data_content; }
```

E os exibo de forma totalmente feia, assim

```
<?php foreach($array_columns as $index => $columns_content) { ?>
    <span><?php print_r( $columns_content ); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
<?php foreach($array_data as $index => $data_content) { ?>
    <span><?php print_r( $data_content ); ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Como faço para ficar apenas os campos com valores e os valores deles ao lado deles

exemplo

Nome do contato (contacts_form_name) : Fye flourigh

Obs.: não posso limitar quais campos verei  na busca mysql pois não seis quais campos cada usuário criou, por isso tenho que rodar um show columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, desculpe-me se a minha resposta não for o que você está querendo, pois, não consegui entender direito sua pergunta.

```
for($i=0;$i < count($data_content);$i++) { // Faz um loop para pegar todos os elemento da array $data_content.
if($data_content[$i] != null) { // Se o valor do elemento da array for diferente de vazio ele continua
  if($i == 1) { // Se o valor do elemento da array for um(contacts_form_name)
    echo "Nome do contato:" . $data_content[$i] . "\n";
  }
  if($i == 2) { // Se o valor do elemento da array ser dois(whatsapp)
    echo "Whatsapp do contato:" . $data_content[$i] . "\n";
  }
  if($i == 3) { // Se o valor do elemento da array ser três(email)
    echo "Email do contato:" . $data_content[$i] . "\n";
  }
  if($i == 4) { // Se o valor do elemento da array ser quatro(site)
    echo "Site do contato:" . $data_content[$i] . "\n";
  }
  if($i == 5) { // Se o valor do elemento da array ser cinco(facebook)
    echo "Facebook do contato:" . $data_content[$i] . "\n";
  }
  if($i == 6) { // Se o valor do elemento da array ser igual a seis(messenger)
    echo "Messenger do contato:" . $data_content[$i] . "\n";
  }
}
}
```

Não sei se é permitido postar links de emuladores externos, se não for alguem me avise por favor, mas está aqui um exemplo http://ideone.com/kj9fu1.

Comment: a primeira parte acho que ajuda bastante no que preciso, irei testar o mais rápido possível, já as partes abaixo não sei se irá ajudar pois o problema é, não sei quais são os campos que o usuário criou, o whatsapp, Messenger e email é apenas exemplo, cada banco de dados tem os campos que o usuário determina, no caso, onde fica os nomes do campo que você pôs i = n• isso teria que ser dinâmico, mas pode por emuladores externos sim.

Comment: então, olhando o emulador, é exatamente isso que desejo para a primeira parte, era este que eu não estava conseguindo elaborar, mas, como seria para um número infinito, no lugar de colocar 1...6 como faria para ser infinito e pegar o nome do array1, no array1 ficam os nomes dos campos que o usuário escreveu e no array2 que você fez ficam os valores.

Comment: @Flourigh Desculpe a demora. Mas bom, eu dei uma olhada novamente na sua pergunta e eu acho que agora eu entendi(eu acho que você fica muito afobado quando digita, antes de "aperter Enter", lê o seu propio texto, porque vai facilitar quem responder). Se a sua pergunta foi que você queria mostrar por exemplo: _contacts_form_name : Fye Flourigh_ era só ao inves de utilizar o elemento `if`, pegar "id" dos elementos da variavel `$columns_content` e sincronizar com os ID da `$data_content`. Exemplo:
`echo $columns_content[$i] . " : " . $data_content[$i] . "\n";`

Comment: O link da resposta acima no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/1jMvaj)

Comment: Seu código é muito bom, mas estou com uma dificuldade extrema, meu array não fica bonito como o seu, ele fica todo cheio de informação, acho que multidimensional, como faço para deixar o array deste exemplo http://ideone.com/FrHa2K igual ao seu?

Comment: um dos arrays eu consegui, mas o de columns que é muito complexo está bem difícil

Comment: @Nobih consegui graças a outra pergunta que fiz, funcionou bem quando juntei o seu com o dele [link = http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/125271/diminuir-um-array-multidimencional/125283#125283]diminuir-um-array-multidimencional[/link]