# Diminuir um array multidimencional

Tags: php, foreach

Boa noite, estou com um dilema, tenho tentado de muitas formas mas meu conhecimento com array ainda é vago, gostaria de ajuda no seguinte, eu tenho dois arrays, um deles eu já resolvi com um foreach pois era um array simples assim como este modelo

```
$data_content = Array
    (
        0 => null,
        1 => 'Fye Flourigh',
        2 => '+5521888',
        3 => null,
        4 => null,
        5 => null,
        6 => null
    );
```

mas o segundo array é bem esquisito, eu preciso fazer com que este array2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [COLUMN_COMMENT] => 
            [0] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [COLUMN_COMMENT] => Nome do contato
            [0] => Nome do contato
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [COLUMN_COMMENT] => Whatsapp
            [0] => Whatsapp
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [COLUMN_COMMENT] => Email
            [0] => Email
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [COLUMN_COMMENT] => Site
            [0] => Site
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [COLUMN_COMMENT] => Facebook
            [0] => Facebook
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [COLUMN_COMMENT] => Messenger
            [0] => Messenger
        )

)
```

fique igual ao array 1 para eu poder utilizar

segue dois links para tentar entender.
este link 1 mostra como deve ficar http://ideone.com/1jMvaj

e este link 2 mostra como está http://ideone.com/FrHa2K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve fazer o mesmo que fez antes, porém somente capturando aquilo que deseja, no caso o $array[0] dentro de um loop, ou não.

*Aparentemente já possui conhecimento sobre o `for`, portanto irei usa-lo.*

```
// Sua array:
$array = array(
    array
        (
            'COLUMN_COMMENT' => '',
            '0' => ''
        ),
    array
        (
            'COLUMN_COMMENT' => 'Nome do contato',
            '0' => 'Nome do contato'
        ),
    array
        (
            'COLUMN_COMMENT' => 'Whatsapp',
            '0' => 'Whatsapp'
        ),
    array
        (
            'COLUMN_COMMENT' => 'Email',
            '0' => 'Email'
        ),
    array
        (
            'COLUMN_COMMENT' => 'Site',
            '0' => 'Site'
        ),
    array
        (
            'COLUMN_COMMENT' => 'Facebook',
            '0' => 'Facebook'
        ),
    array
        (
            'COLUMN_COMMENT' => 'Messenger',
            '0' => 'Messenger'
        )
);
```

```
$contagemArray = count($array);
// Quantidade de array existentes : 7

for($idArray=0; $idArray < $contagemArray; $idArray++) { 

  $atualArray = $array[$idArray];  
  // Array selecionada (0, 1, 2, 3)...

  $data_content[] = $atualArray[0];
  // Seleciona o valor "0" da array selecionada anteriormente. 

}
```

*O $data_content irá conter:*

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  [1]=>
  string(15) "Nome do contato"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Whatsapp"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Email"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "Site"
  [5]=>
  string(8) "Facebook"
  [6]=>
  string(9) "Messenger"
}
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, mas você comentou sobre fazer com for, teria outra forma? seria qual? foreach ou to doido? só por curiosidade, mas funcionou bem aqui, Agradecido.

Comment: Existe o foreach e existe o while, dentro de cada situação pode fazer de várias formas.

Comment: se não for abuso, e quando estiver tempo, poderia por um em foreach para eu ver? é que estou aprendendo então ajudaria.